# Proving $3n^{2}+3n+1\leq \frac{1}{6}\left(n^{3}-n\right)$ for most of $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove that for most of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (I believe for every $n\geq 20$):

$$
3n^{2}+3n+1\leq \frac{1}{6}\left(n^{3}-n\right)
$$

I could prove it with induction but I trying to find a shorter way of proving this theorem. I have tried to play with $n$ but I can't seem to see the trick. How can I prove it without induction?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
$$ 18n^2+18n+6 \leq n^3-n $$
$$ 18n(n+1) + 6 \leq n(n^2-1) $$
$$ 6 \leq n(n+1)(n-1)-18n(n+1) $$
$$ 6 \leq n(n+1)(n-19) $$
The right side will be postive, not equal to zero and greater than $6$ for only $n \geq 20$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is a cubic with a positive leading coefficient. Hence it is eventually always true, so holds "for most $n$".

Answer (score 0):

If $\, n\ge 20\,$ then

$$ 18\cdot n^2\,+\,19\cdot n\,+\, 6\,<\,
    19\cdot n^2\,<\, n^3$$

hence

$$ 18\cdot n^2\,+\,18\cdot n\,+\, 6\,<\, n^3-n$$

i.e.

$$ 3\cdot n^2\,+\,3\cdot n\,+\,1 \,<\, \frac{n^3-n}6 $$

*Great!*